# TeXLive and TeXstudio error when compiling any file

Tags: texlive, texstudio, compilation-error

I installed `texlive` and `texstudio`but I'm always getting the same error when I try to compile any file. The error that outputs to `texput.log` is the following:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2023.7.31)  31 JUL 2023 22:21
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**monografia.tex

! Emergency stop.
<*> monografia.tex
                  
*** (job aborted, file error in nonstop mode)

 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 3 strings out of 477985
 117 string characters out of 5840058
 1849388 words of memory out of 5000000
 20305 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 512287 words of font info for 32 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 0i,0n,0p,1b,6s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

The file content I'm trying to compile:

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
    Simple test.
\end{document}
```

I tried to uninstall and do a clean build when installing `texlive` and `textudio` again, but the error persists.